# How to print list from the ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, viewbag

I want to print the products details along with the category name in view. I used ViewBag for it. **How to access the or print it in view
    Here are the domain classes and the context class**

```
public partial class Category  
{  
public int CategoryID { get; set; }  
public string CategoryName { get; set; }  
public string Description { get; set; }  
public byte[] Picture { get; set; }  
}

public partial class Product
{
public int ProductID { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> SupplierID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

**and the Action method is**

```
public ActionResult Products()
    {
        var productList = (from p in db.Products
                          join c in db.Categories 
                          on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                          select new { ProductID=p.ProductID, ProductName=p.ProductName, CategoryName =c.CategoryName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductsList = productList;
        return View();
    }
```

**and the view Products.cshtml is**

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border:dotted">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Produdt Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.ProductsList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ProductID</td>  
            <td>@item.ProductName</td>
            <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

**It is returning exception.**
Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ProductID'
**Please correct me. andd thank you very much**

Comment: When you wan to do (learn) MVC, avoid the ViewBag. Your list should be part of a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

As bommelding noted, you should try to avoid the ViewBag and use strongly typed ViewModels instead.

That being said, your problem is that ViewBag is basically an `IDictionary<string, object>`. So if you access `ViewBag["ProductsList"]`, you will get an `object`, and therefore the error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ProductID'

You need to cast this `object` to the original type to access the properties. But you do not have an original type to cast to because you used an anonymous type to fill the ViewBag in the first place.

The clean solution is to introduce ViewModels:

```
public class ProductViewModel {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsPageViewModel {
    public ProductsPageViewModel {
        ProductsList = new List<ProductViewModel>();
    }

    public ICollection<ProductViewModel> ProductsList { get; set; }
}
```

Pass the ViewModel to the View in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Products() {
    var productList = 
        (from p in db.Products
         join c in db.Categories 
         on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
         select new ProductViewModel { 
             ProductID = p.ProductID, 
             ProductName = p.ProductName, 
             CategoryName = c.CategoryName 
         }).ToList();

    var viewModel = new ProductsPageViewModel {
        ProductsList = productList 
    };
    return View("Products", viewModel);
}
```

In the Products.cshtml View, define which ViewModel you are expecting with the `@model` directive:

```
@model ProductsPageViewModel 

@* ... *@

@foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList) {
    @item.ProductID
}
```

Comment: Thanks you George for your answer. It has really helped me

Comment: Always glad to help :)